# Rails 3.2 xsendfile not working

Tags: ruby, apache, ruby-on-rails-3.2, apache2, x-sendfile

I have to download static files which need authentication.
I am following http://makandracards.com/makandra/990-speed-up-file-downloads-with-rails-apache-and-x-sendfile and https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/

I have set `config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache` in production.rb

Controller:

```
send_file("#{Rails.root}/private/myfile.mp3",
            :filename => "myfile.mp3",                
            type: "audio/mpeg",
            :disposition => 'inline')
```

Apache configuration:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>  
  ServerName myserver.com

  RequestHeader Set X-Sendfile-Type X-Sendfile
  XSendFile On
  XSendFilePath /sites/releases
  RailsEnv production
</VirtualHost>
```

Even though, I put this, it is not sending any x-sendfile header.
It is strange but if I remove X-Sendfile On and X-SendfilePath, then it sets X-Sendfile header but the file does not play in browser.

I am trying this for three days, I have read everything available on google.

I have a feeling I'm missing something simple. If anyone has any suggestions, please let me
know!
Thanks.

Comment: have you tried to specify x-sendifile and stream also in your send_file request and in headers, like this:`response.headers["X-Sendfile"]=  filename

      send_file filename, 
      :disposition => :inline, :stream => true, :x_sendfile => true`

Comment: @sissy, x-sendfile: true is deprecated in rails 3